# CF 3.5 memory leak - why is components instantiated, but components.Add(...) never called?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, compact-framework

I've noticed a memory leak in my Compact Framework 3.5 application, and I think I've spotted why: the components are never added to my form's `IContainer components` field. Why is it that Visual Studio 2008 does not add each component, and is there any way to fix this?

```
//Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try {
        if (disposing && components != null) {
            // Components is disposed... but nothing was ever added to it!!!
            components.Dispose();

        }
    } finally {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

//Required by the Windows Form Designer

private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
//NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
//It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
//Do not modify it using the code editor.
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.lblName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.butNext = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.butPrev = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.butClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.butMore = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    //
    //lblName
    //
    this.lblName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
    this.lblName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 38);
    this.lblName.Name = "lblName";
    this.lblName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(373, 22);
    this.lblName.Tag = "Estimated Speed ({0})";
    this.lblName.Text = "Test";

            // ... SNIP ...
    }
```

Comment: You are not using any Components, only Controls.  They get disposed by their Parent.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a memory leak.  Your form doesn't really have a `components` field - this is only instantiated and used at design time.

You may be thinking of your form's `Controls` collection instead.  The code you posted has been standard in .NET since the Pleistocene - do you really think Microsoft would miss something this big all these years?

If you do have a memory leak (how have you determined this?), it is almost certainly the result of not calling `Dispose()` on all the objects that need to have `Dispose()` called on them.  .NET does a great job with garbage collection, but it's not 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Controls are components but not all components are controls.  This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164159.aspx) might provide some useful background.  The 'components' IContainer is there to hold any non-control components that have to be disposed of.

The form's controls should be disposed of via the 'Controls' property.  Somewhere below your 'snip' you should see code similar to

```
this.Controls.Add(this.lblName);
```